# Heroku not recognizing local image paths it insteads says Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

Locally, my images load fine. Upon deploying to Heroku, everything works but when a feature tries to load an image it fails. Heroku logs state - "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL", with the type being the image it's trying to load.

This is not a HTML app. This is a DiscordJS Bot, with 5 images stored locally. Certain commands post these images in the corresponding discord channel. This works perfectly local.

The file structure for the images is as follows....

```
src
 - utilities
 - imageloader.js
 - image1.png
 - image2.png
 - image3.png
 - image4.png
 - image5.png
```

I am using this path to load the images locally

```
path = "image1.png"
```

This works locally but breaks with Heroku. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I needed to use relative path